# After json_decode losing about 22 some Characters

Tags: php, json

Im trying to decode a a json file in php.

```
function ReturnJson(){
    $json_data =  json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
    for ($i = 0, $len = count($json_data); $i< $len; ++$i){

        $json_data[$i]['num'] = (string) ($i +1);
    }
    print_r($json_data);
    return $json_data;   
   }
```

However here I notice that I am missing about 20 characters in the array that are missing from my original file.

Thoughts?

Ok here is a small snippet of the json document, its huge but the beginning itself differs from the original

Small original file:

```
  {"events":[{"control":null,"submitter":{"deviceId":"1","sessionId":"1"},"variables":[{"scope":"SESSION","value":"iPhone OS","name":"osName"},{"scope":"SESSION","value":"x86_64","name":"hardwareType"},{"scope":"SESSION","value":"6.0","name":"osVersion"},{"scope":"EVENT","value":"51115abd1e0422c533000002","name":"variant"}],"label":null,"category":null,"location":"ADSettingsViewController","timestamp":"2012-11-16T19:23:57Z","action":null,"type":"PAGEVIEW","versionNumber":"1.0","value":0,"submitted":0,"appId":"50fdc396b9efd172b8000065","controlEvent":null},{"control":null,"submitter":{"deviceId":"1","sessionId":"1"},"variables":[{"scope":"SESSION","value":"iPhone OS","name":"osName"},{"scope":"SESSION","value":"x86_64","name":"hardwareType"},{"scope":"SESSION","value":"6.0","name":"osVersion"},{"scope":"EVENT","value":"51115abd1e0422c533000002","name":"variant"}],"label":null,"category":null,"location":"ADProductViewController","timestamp":"2012-11-16T19:23:59Z","action":null,"type":"PAGEVIEW","versionNumber":"1.0","value":0,"submitted":0,"appId":"50fdc396b9efd172b8000065","controlEvent":null}
```

What comes out:

```
 {"control":null,"submitter":{"deviceId":"1","sessionId":"1"},"variables":[{"scope":"SESSION","value":"iPhone OS","name":"osName"},{"scope":"SESSION","value":"x86_64","name":"hardwareType"},{"scope":"SESSION","value":"6.0","name":"osVersion"},{"scope":"EVENT","value":"51115abd1e0422c533000002","name":"variant"}],"label":null,"category":null,"location":"ADSettingsViewController","timestamp":"2013-02-25T16:22:57Z","action":null,"type":"PAGEVIEW","versionNumber":"1.0","value":0,"submitted":0,"appId":"50fdc396b9efd172b8000065","controlEvent":null}{"control":null,"submitter":{"deviceId":"1","sessionId":"1"},"variables":[{"scope":"SESSION","value":"iPhone OS","name":"osName"},{"scope":"SESSION","value":"x86_64","name":"hardwareType"},{"scope":"SESSION","value":"6.0","name":"osVersion"},{"scope":"EVENT","value":"51115abd1e0422c533000002","name":"variant"}],"label":null,"category":null,"location":"ADProductViewController","timestamp":"2013-02-25T16:22:57Z","action":null,"type":"PAGEVIEW","versionNumber":"1.0","value":0,"submitted":0,"appId":"50fdc396b9efd172b8000065","controlEvent":null}{"control":"UIRoundedRectButton","submitter":{"deviceId":"1","sessionId":"1"},"variables":[{"scope":"SESSION","value":"iPhone OS","name":"osName"},{"scope":"SESSION","value":"x86_64","name":"hardwareType"},{"scope":"SESSION","value":"6.0","name":"osVersion"},{"scope":"EVENT","value":"51115abd1e0422c533000002","name":"variant"}],"label":"Checkout Now","category":"ADProductViewController","location":null,"timestamp":"2013-02-25T16:22:57Z","action":"checkoutNowTapped:","type":"EVENT","versionNumber":"1.0","value":0,"submitted":0,"appId":"50fdc396b9efd172b8000065","controlEvent":"UIControlEventTouchUpInside"}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of not working input data?

Comment: `print_r($json_data);` before your loop. It's likely you are overwriting data in your loop.

Comment: Posted! And I did print_r($json_data); same issue I can tell the beginning is missing.

Comment: So I realized, it is throwing away commas when encodes, so when I decode the new file those couple of characters dont get in there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing your data, but a possible cause would be indices that are not sequential (`0, 2, 5, 6` instead of `0, 1, 2, 3`).

If you are not sure what the data contains, you'd better use `foreach` to loop over your array:

```
foreach ($json_data as $key => $value) 
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: So yes that did help, However, The issue was one of my foreach was removing commas and beginning of the file for some reason